# Shell "sub search" with ctrl-r

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Is there a way to do a "sub search" with ctrl-r. Say I want to search for "find" and then search in the results for something else. The search doesn't seem to be a regular expression in zsh at least, so something like "find.*foo" doesn't work.

Comment: In zsh you can use `ESC x history-incremental-pattern-search-backward` to search history for a pattern. Unfortunately the pattern is a glob-style pattern, not a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It's the solution I was looking for. Glob-style matching is enough for me and requires less typing.

Comment: OK, I've now posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zsh you can use <kbd>ESC x history-incremental-pattern-search-backward</kbd> to search history for a pattern. Unfortunately the pattern is a glob-style pattern, not a regular expression.

Most terminal emulators will allow the use of <kbd>Alt-X</kbd> instead of <kbd>ESC x</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I’m answering about `bash`.

Neither `reverse-search-history` (the function bound to `Ctrl-r`), nor history expansion (by which you can re-invoke the last `find` command typing `!ls`, or print it typing `!ls:p`) support globbing or regexes.

Your best option is

```
history | grep 'find.*foo'
```

to look for the regex 'find.*foo' in the the command history (you can also give, say, `history 20`, to restrict the search to the last 20 commands in history).